# Apache RewriteEngine is not working with virtual host setup

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache

I have a basic virtual host setup enabled on my machine, and it works fine when I just type in the server name.  However, when I include "RewriteEngine On" it kills it.  Yes, I do have the rewrite module installed, and yes, I have restarted apache.  I'm not actually attempting any rewrite rules yet, because just the act of turning the thing on is enough to make it stop working.  Any clue as to what's going on?  Seems like if the module is included, this ought to work.  What am I forgetting?  Here's what I've got in my virtual host file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/mysite/public/"
    ServerName mysite

    RewriteEngine on
    <Directory "C:/www/mysite/public/"
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I remove the "RewriteEngine on" line, everything works.  When I put it back in, it breaks.  I could understand if I had some weird rule in there, but simply turning it on shouldn't break anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "kills it"? What do the apache error logs say?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps mod_rewrite isn't enabled in your setup? You can try to put the RewriteEngine On line inside an  test like so

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you an Ubuntu-like system.

Go to /etc/apache2/sites-available/your_site.conf

Open your_site.conf using your favorite text editor.

Add/Update the Directory section as below

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Save it and restart apache.